# how to format number in grid view footer and in ItemTemplate in this format ("###,###.000")

Tags: html, css, asp.net

how to format number in grid view footer and in ItemTemplate in this format ("###,###.000")

footer in html :

```
       <FooterTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="totallblCredAmount" runat="server" />
     </FooterTemplate>
```

footer In code :

```
 if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
   {

       Label totallblCAmount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("totallblDebAmount");
       totallblCAmount.Text = ViewState["TotalPric"].ToString();

       Label totallblCredAmount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("totallblCredAmount");
       totallblCredAmount.Text = ViewState["TotalPrice"].ToString();

   }
```

ItemTemplate html :

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="credit">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Label  runat="server" Text='<%#(Eval("credit"))%>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>  
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: You have to parse the string value to `decimal`, then you can use `decimal.ToString("###,###.000")`. What is the datasource of the `GridView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse the string value to `decimal`, then you can use `decimal.ToString("###,###.000")`.  But if you store the `double` or `decimal` value in `ViewState` you just need to cast it accordingly instead of using `ToString` to convert it to a `string`.

So maybe:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
{
   Label totallblCAmount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("totallblDebAmount");
   decimal pricValue = (decimal)ViewState["TotalPric"];
   totallblCAmount.Text = pricValue.ToString("###,###.000");

   Label totallblCredAmount = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("totallblCredAmount");
   decimal priceValue = (decimal)ViewState["TotalPrice"];
   totallblCAmount.Text = priceValue.ToString("###,###.000");
}
```

If you store a string you have to parse it as  previously mentioned:

```
 string stringPriceValue = (string)ViewState["TotalPrice"];
 decimal priceValue = decimal.Parse( stringPriceValue );
 totallblCAmount.Text = priceValue.ToString("###,###.000");
```

I advise against storing a decimal-number value as string, not only because you always have to parse it, but mainly because you are open for localization issues then.

---

According to your question in the comment on how to format the label in the `ItemTemplate`. If you want to do that on aspx you could do:

```
<asp:Label  runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "credit", "{0:###,###.000}") %>' ID="LblCredit"></asp:Label>
```

Another way is to use codebehind. I'd use `RowDataBound` for this.

```
protected void GrdidView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // note that i've assigned an ID to the label
        Label lblCredit = (Label) e.Row.FindControl("LblCredit");
        DataRow row = ((DataRowView) e.Row.DataItem).Row;  // maybe you need to change the type of the dataitem
        double credit = row.Field<double>("credit");
        lblCredit.Text = credit.ToString("###,###.000");
    }
}
```

Comment: it's return an error in        decimal pricValue = (decimal)ViewState["TotalPric"];    the error is (Specified cast is not valid.)

Comment: @rere: then what is it that you store there? Maybe a `double` or (as mentioned) a `string`. Only you and the debugger know.

Comment: than you it works now but what about format the item template do you know how ???